"drush site:install ... " denied access to database and module not found exception
I am using the below drush command to install a Drupal site, but this results in an access denial to database and failure to find an installed module existing in the right directory and already installed based on composer.json and composer.lock files.
    ./bin/drush --ansi --verbose site:install abc --site-name="$SITE_NAME" --yes --locale="en" --account-name="$ADMIN_NAME" --account-mail="$ADMIN_MAIL" --account-pass="$ADMIN_PASS" 

Here is a part of the output indicating the access denial to database, and an exception about module not found :
 [debug] Add service modifier [0.12 sec, 8.66 MB]
 [info] Executing: command -v mysql [0.12 sec, 9.12 MB]
 [info] sql:query: SELECT 1; [0.13 sec, 9.15 MB]
 [info] Executing: mysql --defaults-file=/tmp/drush_QZmlj6 --database=abc --host=localhost --port=3306 --silent -A < /tmp/drush_2woVyL [0.13 sec, 9.16 MB]
 You are about to:
 * CREATE the 'abc' database.

 // Do you want to continue?: yes.                                              
 [info] Sites directory sites/default already exists - proceeding. [0.15 sec, 9.66 MB]

 [info] sql:query: SELECT 1; [0.15 sec, 9.66 MB]
 [info] Executing: mysql --defaults-file=/tmp/drush_3fNjzc --database=abc --host=localhost --port=3306 --silent -A < /tmp/drush_oHydmi [0.15 sec, 9.66 MB]
 [info] sql:query: DROP DATABASE IF EXISTS abc; CREATE DATABASE abc /*!40100 DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8 */; [0.16 sec, 9.66 MB]
 [info] Executing: mysql --defaults-file=/tmp/drush_TDznW1 --database=information_schema --host=localhost --port=3306 --silent -A < /tmp/drush_bYDBP7 [0.16 sec, 9.66 MB]
 [warning] Failed to drop or create the database. Do it yourself before installing. ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'abc'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
 [0.17 sec, 9.66 MB]
 [notice] Starting Drupal installation. This takes a while. [0.17 sec, 9.66 MB]
 [debug] Calling install_drupal(Composer\Autoload\ClassLoader, array, array) [0.18 sec, 9.9 MB]
 [notice] Performed install task: install_select_language [0.5 sec, 22.1 MB]
 [notice] Performed install task: install_select_profile [0.5 sec, 22.1 MB]
 [notice] Performed install task: install_load_profile [0.5 sec, 22.1 MB]
 [warning] Undefined array key "value" install.core.inc:2306 [0.58 sec, 26.43 MB]

In install.core.inc line 2314:
                                                                               
  [Drupal\Core\Installer\Exception\InstallerException]                         
  Database settings:<br /><br />Resolve all issues below to continue the inst  
  allation. For help configuring your database server, see the <a href="https  
  ://www.drupal.org/docs/installing-drupal">installation handbook</a>, or con  
  tact your hosting provider.<div class="item-list"><ul><li>Failed to connect  
   to your database server. The server reports the following message: <em cla  
  ss="placeholder">SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access denied for user &#039;abc&#0  
  39;@&#039;localhost&#039; (using password: YES)</em>.<ul><li>Is the databas  
  e server running?</li><li>Does the database exist or does the database user  
   have sufficient privileges to create the database?</li><li>Have you entere  
  d the correct database name?</li><li>Have you entered the correct username   
  and password?</li><li>Have you entered the correct database hostname and po  
  rt number?</li></ul></li></ul></div>                                         
                                                                               
  Required modules:Required modules not found.<br /><br />The following modul  
  es are required but were not found. Move them into the appropriate modules   
  subdirectory, such as <em>/modules</em>. Missing modules: <div class="item-  
  list--comma-list item-list"><ul class="item-list__comma-list"><li><span cla  
  ss="admin-missing">Private_files_download_permission</span></li></ul></div>  
                                                                               

Exception trace:
  at /var/www/abc/web/core/includes/install.core.inc:2314
...

What I have searched and verified :

I have tried successfully the mysql credentials provided in settings.local.php.
I have captured a copy of the credentials that drush site:install used to connect to mysql from temporary files, and these credentials are as expected and provided in settings.local.php.
I have checked mysql errors log file, and this confirms the access denial hit by drush site:install command.
I have granted manually the used mysql user full access to the database, in vain.
I am using a password that is special character free.
I have tried to provide the same credentials via the --db-url option, but the resulting failure output is still the same.
I have verified that the module private_files_download_permission is installed by examining the modules/contrib directory, and by using composer to list installed modules.


If you're pre-populating the credentials from code, try adding $databases directly to settings.php, instead of settings.local.php. I've had instances in the past where the installer writes its own copy of $databases to settings.php, and it ends up conflicting. For the module, what does composer show drupal/private_files_download_permission | grep path tell you?

I noticed drush is in bin/drush rather that vendor/bin/drush. That’s unusual.

Which versions of drush and drupal are you using?

Thanks for all contributors,
Here are complementary required  info:
Drush version  : 11.6.0
Drupal version : 10.1.8
php version : 8.2.22
bin/drush is tested successfully as a symlink to vendor/drush/drush/drush .
@Clive Here is an indication of the path exploration command :  composer show drupal/private_files_download_permission | grep path
path  :    mySiteRootPath/web/modules/contrib/private_files_download_permission

Thanks @Clive setting the credentials in settings.php instead of settings.local.php solved the database connection issue, but "drush install:site ..." is still hitting the already mentioned exception:
In install.core.inc line 2314:
Required modules:Required modules not found.The following modul
es are required ......
Private_files_download_permission
Exception trace:
at /var/www/pmt/web/core/includes/install.core.inc:2314

The answer to the question is two-folded:

First part:  The Module not found error is due to the fact that drush do not recognize the module name private_files_download_permission, but it recognizes it as pfdp. This was referred to in another issue.

That said, I have replaced "private_files_download_permission" with "pfdp"  in the dependencies list in the file web/profiles/pmt/pmt.info.yml and this solved the problem of  Module not found error that the command "drush site:install .. " hit . "pmt" in the path indicated above refers to the actual name of the site I have installed, and that was referred to by "abc" in my initial question.

Second part: the "Access denied" problem is now solved by setting $databases for database access credentials directly in settings.php avoiding the use of inclusion of settings.local.php , and by making sure that the $databases variable in this file is not overwritten by any subsequent instructions in the same file settings.php as explained below . I have also granted manually the database user a full access to drop tables and more on the database.

It is worth it to mention here that when we execute repeatedly the command "drush site:install ... " because of repeated failures of the command, using the option --db-url or other means to specify DB access credentials, the command can write to the file settings.php instructions specifying credentials via $databases variable to access the database; and this can overwrite subsequent specifications of the $databases variable by subsequent execution of the command " drush site:install ... " .  A walkthrough settings.php before and after a failing drush site:install command can reveal setting differently many times the $databases variable, and this was a cause of DB access denial error.
Thanks, and special regards for the authors of the helpful answers and comments about this question,
JA-user

The first warning is:

[warning] Failed to drop or create the database. Do it yourself before
installing. ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user
'abc'@'localhost' (using password: YES)  [0.17 sec, 9.66 MB]

I suggest starting by investigating and resolving that issue. Everything else is a consequence of the failure to create the site database.
I've found that insufficient disk space is a common culprit of these kind of issues, so maybe start there.

Hi @ergonlogic , the "Access denied" issue is now solved by mainly setting $databases directly in settings.php
The remaining issue that "drush site:install .." is still hitting a Modules not found exception for the module private_files_download_permission as follows:
Required modules:Required modules not found... Move them into the appropriate modules   ...   subdirectory, such as .... Private_files_download_permission
Exception trace:
at /var/www/pmt/web/core/includes/install.core.inc:2314
